# If we want to fetch linelevel details of invoice which is connected to sales order using suiteQL

Tags: suiteql

Actually I am getting invoice details through the sales order but not getting details of linelevel data of invoice then my question is how to fetch this details using suiteql.

```
SELECT DISTINCT NTo.tranid AS 'invoice tranid' ,
FROM NextTransactionLineLink AS NTLLo 
INNER JOIN Transaction AS NTo ON NTo.ID = NTLLo.NextDoc
 WHERE NTLLo.PreviousDoc = t.id
 AND NTo.Type = 'CustInvc' `This is my query and I want item information using above details`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I didn't get what the alias 't' is for here.
" WHERE NTLLo.PreviousDoc = t.id "
But if you want line level items, you will get that from the transactionline table.
The join would look smth like this :

```
SELECT * FROM transaction 
LEFT JOIN transactionline 
ON transaction.id = transactionline.transaction
```